# What is the difference between ls -ls and ls -l?

Tags: ubuntu

These are the commands I am trying. If i write

```
$ ls -ls
```

in Ubuntu terminal then it shows

```
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 27599 27599  978 Feb 13 18:25 README.txt
```

If I write

```
$ ls -l
```

then it shows

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 27599 27599  978 Feb 13 18:25 README.txt
```

I am confused why the first command shows a digit number "4" but the 2nd does not. How it is happening?

Comment: Why did you think changing the flags *wouldn't* make a difference? Did you try reading `man ls`, which explains every flag? What do you mean *"how"*?

Comment: yes i have read  **man ls**  actually i am new to Ubuntu

Comment: how means . why firrst command shows numeric number and 2nd does not shows

Comment: OK, so what do you still not understand? If you're changing the inputs, why is it surprising that the outputs change? Also note that just using the terminal isn't actually programming.

Comment: yes i know . different inputs have different outputs. but thing that i want to explore  is that what are the main purpose of these commands, as you can see both are listing the files and directories . but first one listing the directory , beaning with a numeric value and the 2nd command list the directries does hot shows any numeric value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `ls -l` and `ls -ls` in the most general case is that `ls -ls` will show more information since the `s` is an additional option. Let's take a closer look at the options though and the outputs from them.

Here is an example from a random directory on macOS (so on Ubuntu things might be slightly different).

**ls -l**

> -l      (The lowercase letter ``ell''.)  List in long format.  (See below.)  If the output is to a terminal, a total sum for all the file sizes is output on a line before the long listing.

```
ls -l
total 56
drwxr-xr-x  12 bhaugen  staff   384 Feb 12 09:35 app
drwxr-xr-x   4 bhaugen  staff   128 Feb 11 16:16 build
-rw-r--r--   1 bhaugen  staff   889 Feb 12 09:35 build.gradle
drwxr-xr-x   3 bhaugen  staff    96 Oct 26 10:42 gradle
-rw-r--r--   1 bhaugen  staff   730 Oct 26 10:42 gradle.properties
-rwxr-xr-x   1 bhaugen  staff  4971 Oct 26 10:42 gradlew
-rw-r--r--   1 bhaugen  staff  2404 Oct 26 10:42 gradlew.bat
-rw-r--r--   1 bhaugen  staff   347 Feb 12 09:34 local.properties
drwxr-xr-x   8 bhaugen  staff   256 Feb 12 09:35 number-keyboard
-rw-r--r--   1 bhaugen  staff    58 Oct 26 10:42 settings.gradle
```

**ls -s**

> -s      Display the number of file system blocks actually used by each file, in units of 512 bytes, where partial units are rounded up to the
>   next integer value.  If the output is to a terminal, a total sum for
>   all the file sizes
>                is output on a line before the listing.  The environment variable BLOCKSIZE overrides the unit size of 512 bytes

```
ls -s
total 56
 0 app                 0 build               8 build.gradle        0 gradle              8 gradle.properties  16 gradlew             8 gradlew.bat         8 local.properties    0 number-keyboard     8 settings.gradle
```

Now, let's combine the `-l` and `-s` option!

**ls -ls**

```
ls -ls
total 56
 0 drwxr-xr-x  12 bhaugen  staff   384 Feb 12 09:35 app
 0 drwxr-xr-x   4 bhaugen  staff   128 Feb 11 16:16 build
 8 -rw-r--r--   1 bhaugen  staff   889 Feb 12 09:35 build.gradle
 0 drwxr-xr-x   3 bhaugen  staff    96 Oct 26 10:42 gradle
 8 -rw-r--r--   1 bhaugen  staff   730 Oct 26 10:42 gradle.properties
16 -rwxr-xr-x   1 bhaugen  staff  4971 Oct 26 10:42 gradlew
 8 -rw-r--r--   1 bhaugen  staff  2404 Oct 26 10:42 gradlew.bat
 8 -rw-r--r--   1 bhaugen  staff   347 Feb 12 09:34 local.properties
 0 drwxr-xr-x   8 bhaugen  staff   256 Feb 12 09:35 number-keyboard
 8 -rw-r--r--   1 bhaugen  staff    58 Oct 26 10:42 settings.gradle
```

As you can see above, when you combine the `-l` and `-s` options you get the long output format including the blocksize of each file. The blocksize is what the `-s` option is showing you and it is why the line begins with a number. It would be awesome if the `ls` command showed headings for the columns, unfortunately it does not.

Comment: Thank you so much **Brandon Haugen**  for helping me .

Comment: When you do `ls -s`, the 8 next to build.gradle denotes that there are 8 blocks of 512 bytes each, meaning that build.gradle contains a total of 4096 bytes. However, when you do `ls -l`, the number next to build.gradle is 889. Could you explain this discrepancy? Thanks so much :)